# get user_id from variable using php

Tags: php, variables, text, joomla2.5

I have this variable `$products` that I'm getting from the db. Now when I print what's in it it shows

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 1 [product_id] => 5363 [category_id] => 209 [price] => 1 [tax] => 18.00 [tax_id] => 1 [description] => [product_name] => test2 [thumb_image] => [ean] => [attributes] => a:0:{} [attributes_value] => Array ( ) [weight] => 0.0000 [vendor_id] => 0 [files] => a:0:{} [freeattributes] => a:0:{} [dependent_attr_serrialize] => a:0:{} [href] => /kategorii/product/view/209/5363.html [free_attributes_value] => Array ( ) ) )
```

So my question is how can i get what is the product_id number?

I print this using `print_r($products);` but is gives me this error

```
Warning: current() [function.current]: Passed variable is not an array or object in ...
```

This is the code that is causing this problem:

```
$cart = JModel::getInstance('cart', 'jshop');
        $cart->load();  
        $products=$cart->products;
        //$productos[0]['product_id'];
        print_r($products);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable you did a print_r of above is assigned to $products:

```
$products[0]['product_id']
```

Comment: What does print_r($cart->products) give you, same thing? How about getting the product id via $cart->products[0]['product_id']